# .htaccess RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rule in my .htaccess file but for some reason I get a 501 server error with the Bag Flag Delimiters message.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(blog|deblog|plblog)$ /$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.de [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.(php|html) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ {NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.de/de/$0 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: typo? `{` -> `[` in line 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have typo, replace:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$  {NC]
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$  [NC]
```